# Нужно ли отключать `toolbar` после уничтожения фрагмента?

Tags: android

У меня есть `MainActivity`, у которой есть меню и общий `toolbar`, а контент меняется фрагментами. Но в одном из `фрагментов` например `TopFragment`, используется свой `toolbar`а из `MainActivity` прячется. Инициализирую `toolbar` внутри `TopFragment` так:

```
mainView.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar actionBar = mainView.getSupportActionBar();

if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener((View v) ->  getActivity().onBackPressed());
```

Кажется из-за этого происходит утечка памяти, вероятно из-за того что Toolbar живет дольше фрагмента. Нужно ли как то отключать `toolbar` после уничтожения `TopFragment`? Если да, то как?

Comment: Вы можете менять айтемы в тулбаре из фрагмента, а не подключать целиком новый тулбар.

Comment: @pavlofff toolbar в TopFragment находится внутри CoordinatorLayout->AppBarLayout->CollapsingToolbarLayout и другие дополнительные view находятся рядом,поэтому думаю что так сделать не получится.

Comment: это делается в переопределенном в фрагменте методе `onCreateOptionMenu()` или `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, где можно добавить/удалить отдельные пункты или подключить целиком другую разметку меню и совершенно не важно как глубоко вложен тулбар.

Comment: @pavlofff У меня используется кастомный toolbar на подобие такого stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/1836605, по этому просто переопределить пункты меню думаю не получится. Либо отказываться от кастомного.

Answer (score 1):

В методе `onCreate` нужного фрагмента добавьте строку:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

А за методом `onCreate` создайте метод `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
}
```

При загрузке вашего фрагмента в меню будет загружаться указанный макет.

Comment: У меня используется кастомный toolbar на подобие такого http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548766/1836605, по этому просто переопределить пункты не получится

Comment: А что конкретно вам нужно переопределить? Потому что при загрузке фрагмента пункт "настройки" в меню тулбара будет заменен тем макетом, который вы укажите в вашем фрагменте, из приведенного мною куска кода это fragment_menu. Если вы, например в этой разметке добавите пункты меню и сделаете чтобы они были на самом тулбаре, то как только вы откроете ваш фрагмент они будут появляться там, а как только закроете или перелистнете то будут пропадать

Comment: А касательно вашего кастомного заголовка в тулбаре, то попробуйте получить на него ссылку из того же фрагмента, и загрузить туда нужный вам текст, если это требуется сделать. TextView my_title = ((TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title));

Answer (score 0):

Утечки памяти не будет, так как `toolbar` просто отдается на управление `activity`. Единственное, что меня смущает - это то, что при возвращении из фрагмента, `toolbar` останется тот, который был установлен `TopFragment`.

Comment: При возвращении в фрагмент, который использует общий toolbar, я вызываю .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); При этом toolbar из TopFragment уже не виден.

Comment: А вот это уже не очень вариант. Лучше при показе конкретного фрагмента подменять `Support Actionbar`. То есть в `TopFragment` ставьте кастомный, а в других дефолтный.

Comment: Я пробовал делать setSupportActionBar в TopFragment, но по факту он добавляется к старому